# query the database to find what Nth is the record

Tags: mysql

I don't know how to writ the Title for this question, but what I need is a query that return what is the `N` record with a specific value.

The table that I have is over 5.2M records

The records are similar to:

- session (string, primary indexed)
- customer_id (int, indexed)
- clicks (int, indexed)
- order_number (int, indexed)
- date_entry (datetime, indexed)
- many other fields

what I need to know is how many times the same customer logged into the site (different sessions) before placing an order (order_number is 0 unless an order is placed during that session)

a sample data can be (simplify data)

```
session | c_id | clicks | ord_num  |         entry        |
abc     | 123  |   2    |    0     | 2012-08-01 00:00:00  |
cde     | 456  |   2    |    0     | 2012-08-01 00:00:01  |
efg     | 457  |   2    |    0     | 2012-08-01 00:00:02  |
hij     | 123  |   5    |    0     | 2012-08-01 00:00:03  |
kod     | 986  |  10    |    0     | 2012-08-01 00:00:04  |
wdg     | 123  |   2    |  9876    | 2012-08-01 00:00:05  |
qwe     | 123  |   2    |    0     | 2012-08-01 00:00:06  |
wvr     | 986  |  12    |  8656    | 2012-08-01 00:00:07  |
```

What I want is a query that shows something similar to:

- entry     - date entry
- tot_sess  - total number of session
- tot_cust  - total number of customers
- 1sess     - customer1 with only one session
- 2sess     - customers with 2 sessions
- 3sess     - customers with 3 sessions
- 4sess     - customers with 4 sessions
- more4sess     - customers with more than 4 sessions
- order1sess    - customers that ordered on the first session
- order2sess    - customers that ordered on the second session
- order3sess    - customers that ordered on the third session
- order4sess    - customers that ordered on the fourth session
- orderMore4Sess    - customers that ordered after the fourth session

```
entry         |tot_sess|tot_cust| 1sess | 2sess | 3sess | 4sess | more4sess | order1sess |  order2sess |  order3sess |  order4sess | orderMore4Sess | 
2012-08-01    |    8   |   4    |   2   |   1   |   0   |   1   |    0      |       0    |    1        |      1      |      0      |      0         |
```

I am already able to get the information about the session with the following query:

```
SELECT
   t.`date_entry`,
   COUNT(sess) `cust`,
   SUM(sess) `session`,
   COUNT(IF(sess>1,sess,NULL)) `more than once`,
   COUNT(IF(sess=1,sess,NULL)) `one`,
   COUNT(IF(sess=2,sess,NULL)) `two`,
   COUNT(IF(sess=3,sess,NULL)) `three`,
   COUNT(IF(sess=4,sess,NULL)) `four`,
   COUNT(IF(sess>4,sess,NULL)) `more`,
   ROUND(COUNT(IF(sess>1,sess,NULL))/COUNT(sess),2) `perc > 1`,
   ROUND(COUNT(IF(sess>2,sess,NULL))/COUNT(sess),2) `perc > 2`,
   ROUND(COUNT(IF(sess>3,sess,NULL))/COUNT(sess),2) `perc > 3`,
   ROUND(COUNT(IF(sess>4,sess,NULL))/COUNT(sess),2) `perc > 4`
FROM
(
SELECT
   `customer_id`,
   COUNT(`session`) `sess`,
   DATE(`date_entry`) `date_entry`
FROM `customer_activity_log`
WHERE
   `clicks` > 1
   AND `customer_id` > 0
   AND `date_entry` > '2012-08-01'
   AND subsite_id <=1
GROUP BY `date_entry`, `customer_id`
) t
GROUP BY date_entry
```

Once I had that I will also need to look at the data in a different way, for example, if customer 123 showed on the first time on 2012-01-01 and then came back 15 times and placed the order on 2012-08-01 and then came back 5 more times and placed another order on 2012-10-12 I will need a query that will not restrain by date but only by customer, in other words the restrain `date_entry` will be removed

I hope it makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT e               AS entry,
       SUM(sessions)   AS tot_sess,
       COUNT(*)        AS tot_cust,
       SUM(sessions=1) AS 1sess,
       SUM(sessions=2) AS 2sess,
       SUM(sessions=3) AS 3sess,
       SUM(sessions=4) AS 4sess,
       SUM(sessions>4) AS more4sess,
       SUM(orders  =1) AS order1sess,
       SUM(orders  =2) AS order2sess,
       SUM(orders  =3) AS order3sess,
       SUM(orders  =4) AS order4sess,
       SUM(orders  >4) AS orderMore4Sess
FROM (
  SELECT b.e, b.c_id, b.sessions, COUNT(a.entry) AS orders
  FROM   customer_activity_log a RIGHT JOIN (
    SELECT   DATE(entry) AS e, c_id, COUNT(*) AS sessions,
             MIN(IF(ord_num=0,NULL,entry)) AS o
    FROM     customer_activity_log
    GROUP BY e, c_id
  ) b ON a.c_id = b.c_id AND DATE(a.entry) = b.e AND a.entry <= b.o
  GROUP BY b.e, b.c_id
) t
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a295f/1/0).

Comment: Thank you. I will have to work a bit and try to speed it up, but it a great query.